# RouterOutlet magic ;) Navbar routerLink with dynamic parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Simplified version of the HTML:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The routing:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/ru/mission', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: ':l/mission', component: AppMissionComponent },
{ path: ':l/courses/categories', component: CourseCategoriesListComponent }
```

Than I got `LanguageService` responsible for providing different translations based on a value of the `:l` parameter (shor for "language"). Consider following piece of code having an instance of an `ActivatedRoute` class:

```
public observe(): Observable<LanguageService> {
    return this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      map(
        params => {
          const currentLanguage = <string>params['l'];
          if (!(currentLanguage in LanguageService.map)) {
            throw new Error(`Unknown language code: "${currentLanguage}".`);
          }

          this.currentLanguage = currentLanguage;
          this.translator = LanguageService.map[currentLanguage]();
          return Observable.create(this);
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

That `LanguageService` is consumed by a `AppNavbarComponent` (see topmost HTML, `<app-navbar />`). Seems to be fine for me, however when I run my server locally and go to the default `localhost:xxxxx` address, `params['l']` is somewhy undefined even though actural url contains it as a result of redirection to the `/ru/...` (so `params['l']` has to be equal `'ru'` there). Moreover, `LanguageService` works OK with whatever rendered **inside** the **single** `router-outlet` (there are no more of those throughout the entire app).

---

Summary:
Most `Angular` tutorial deal with navbars navigating to a static, compile-time known routes, **which is clearly not my case**: my navbar navigation heavily depends upon current value of the `l` parameter and I see no way to make it work (to be clear: I am using `Angular` only third day by now). Please, help me out, I assume some pretty obvious code needed somewhere behide the HTML scene...

Comment: try `console.log(currentLanguage)` what does it says?

Comment: `undefined` when it comes down to the navbar, however whatever is rendered inside the only `router-outlet` I got so far, it is fine and returns actual `l` value.

Comment: It gives undefined in navbar because the route belongs to other component. You need to get the of it in parent component then pass it to the child component